# How to check selected option in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add selected option in my select box using react js. here is my code

```
<Field component='select' name='sample'>
  <option value={1}>option1</option>
  <option value={2}>option2</option>
  <option value={3} {... "selected"}>option3</option>
  <option value={4}>option4</option>
  <option value={5}>option5</option>
</Field>
```

I try already the defaultValue and also adding `selected` but it doesn't work. Did I miss something about my code?

Comment: Are you using any package for `select` option ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use something like this..where the selected value is in the select(value property) react works that way...

```
<select value={yourSelectedStateValue}>
        <option value={1}>option1</option>
        <option value={2}>option2</option>
        <option value={3}>option3</option>
        <option value={4}>option4</option>
        <option value={5}>option5</option>                            
 </select>
```

take a look at [Link Here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value.)

dealing with the statevalue, use the onChange() event...

```
<select value={yourSelectedStateValue} onChange={this.handleSelectOption.bind(this)}>
        <option value={1}>option1</option>
        <option value={2}>option2</option>
        <option value={3}>option3</option>
        <option value={4}>option4</option>
        <option value={5}>option5</option>                            
 </select>


handleSelectOption(e){
   this.setState({
      yourSelectedStateValue: e.target.value,
   })
}
```

Comment: this will work but when you select other option. it always on the selected value. I can't change it to other option

Comment: use the onChange event `onChange={this.handleSelectOption.bind(this)}`. then set the state using  `handleSelectOption(event) { this.setState({yourSelectedStateValue: event.target.value});}`

Answer (score 0):

My solution example is

```
<Form.Select id='oCompId'>
<option  value="-1">--Please select once item--</option>
{ items.map(item => {
   return item.id === targetId ?
          (<option value={item.id} selected>{item.name}</option>) 
         :
         (<option value={item.id} >{item.name}</option>) 
   }
)}
</Form.Select>
```

I show a default selection to the user when it first rendered.